# memory usage by using ps in linux

Tags: memory, ps

I am trying to compare memory usage between my program and sample program which is given
by using ps in linux

mine and sample is written by c++
and I am not sure how to compare how much memory those two programs use by using ps in linux
Thank you very much

Comment: I would start with `man ps` to find out what kind of information you can get from ps.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how much memory is using every process in Linux by using this command

```
top | grep <name>
```

Generally, if you want to list statistics about all the ongoing processes, you can use the 'top' command without making a pipeline.

```
top
```

... which outputs something similar to this:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1050 root      20   0  350m 125m  89m R   82  6.3   4288:11 Xorg                                                                                            
4633 kocko     20   0  972m 309m  28m R   28 15.4   1677:33 amarok                                                                                          
30624 kocko     20   0 1044m 225m  28m S   12 11.2   3:03.23 eclipse                                                                                         
31356 kocko     20   0  434m  60m  22m S    2  3.0 603:29.59 chrome                                                                                          
 1678 kocko     20   0 42972 7480 4764 S    2  0.4 146:14.10 compiz
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into a profiling tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for your memory analysis. IIRC, the Linux memory manager will add new memory to your process when it needs it, but pages out unneeded memory rather than freeing it. So if you use tools like `free` and `ps` you will find memory leaks where there are none.

Update - it may be [ps rather than the memory manager](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html) that is at "fault" here.